# Is there a serious bug in Salesforce Apex Compiler?

Tags: apex

I needed to save a piece of code

> viewstart   =  Datetime.newInstance(Date.today(), Time.newInstance(0,
>   0, 0, 0));

But by mistake entered

> viewstart   =

without even a semicolon it got compiled and saved successfully.

Is there a serious bug in salesforce apex compiler.  Please find the attched screen shot as proof.  How can we trust if such kind of bugs exist, asking just because of my curiosity. I can share the code if you need to check :)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's a feature. The result of an assignment (formally called an lvalue) can also be assigned to another value (formally called an rvalue). For example:

```
Integer x, y;
x = y = 5;
```

This sets both x and y to 5 in a single statement. First, y becomes the lvalue, and assigned the value 5, then x becomes the lvalue and y becomes the rvalue, so x becomes 5 as well.

You can also do this in interesting techniques, such as:

```
if((x = y) == 5) { ...
```

Which assigns y to x and compares that result to 5.

Newlines do not end a statement... Semicolons do. Always pay attention to what you're doing, or you'll find that you've accidentally assigned the wrong value.